# Symfony2 Sonta Admin bundle doesn't work

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

So I have  been working with the sonata admin bundle the last two days. I have followed the instructions exactly @ http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-0/doc/reference/installation.html

This is the error I am getting:

[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
  You have requested a non-existent parameter "doctrine.connections".

I have yet found one bundle for symfony 2 that works with following there documentation. Its frustrating but i have no choice but to use symfony2.

Comment: You are probably trying to use the *doctrine.connections* variable in some config file, while you don't have it. Please show us your config files and the *parameters.ini* file.

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace also?

Comment: No backtrace. I get a 404 if i goto the website or if i work from CLI i get 
  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
  You have requested a non-existent parameter "doctrine.connections".

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VMfLkreq <- a grep of the code

Comment: Sorry no 404 error internal server error.

Comment: Assuming you are using Symfony 2.0 (and not the latest version from the master branch) I would suggest checking the following: Is Doctrine enabled? It should appear in the registerBundles() method in your AppKernel.php. Also please make sure to use the 2.0 branch of the sonata adminbundle. In your deps file you should have version=refs/remotes/origin/2.0 under [SonataAdminBundle]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and removing "version=origin/2.0" from my deps file for all the Sonata bundles fixed the issue after running the update vendors script.